# simple moving objects with sdl library and c++

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-1.2

i developped game "mario bross" with SDL and c++ to simplify things , i have two rectangle and i had to change the coordinates one of them three steps  up (-3) and after three steps down(+3) where ever the two rectangles go throught collision .

the problem is when the two rectangle goes throught collision one of them move up (-3) but it does not move down(+3) i redirect the coordinates of the rectangle it change up and down but it only render the up movement.

```
// surprise.h 
#ifndef SURPRISE_H_INCLUDED
#define SURPRISE_H_INCLUDED
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <vector>
#include "base.h"
class surprise:public baseclass
{
SDL_Rect box;
int xvel,yvel;
SDL_Surface* image;
bool ground;
double frame;
SDL_Rect clips[4];
public:
    surprise(SDL_Surface*,int x,int y,int xvel,int yvel);
    void show(SDL_Surface*);
    void setFrame(double);
     void move(int xvel);
    double getFrame();
    SDL_Rect* getRect();
    int getyvel();
    void setyvel(int y);
};
#endif // SURPRISE_H_INCLUDED

//surprise.cpp
#include"surprise.h"
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
surprise::surprise(SDL_Surface* img ,int x,int y,int xVel,int yVel)
{
image=img;
box.x=x;
box.y=y;
box.w=image->w/2;
box.h=image->h;
xvel=xVel;
yvel=yVel;
ground=0;
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
 {
  clips[i].x=i*30;
  clips[i].y=0;
  clips[i].w=30;
  clips[i].h=30;
 }
frame=0.0;
}
double  surprise::getFrame()
{
return frame;
}
void surprise::setFrame(double fr)
{
frame=fr;
}
void surprise::show(SDL_Surface* screen)
{
SDL_Rect tmp={box.x-coord.x,box.y,30,30};
if (frame>=2)
   {
   frame=0.1;
   SDL_BlitSurface(image,&clips[(int)(frame+0.5)],screen,&tmp);
   }
else
  {
    SDL_BlitSurface(image,&clips[(int)(frame+0.5)],screen,&tmp);
  }
frame+=0.1;
}
SDL_Rect* surprise::getRect()
{
return &box;
}
int surprise::getyvel()
{
return box.y;
}
void surprise::setyvel(int y)
{
box.y+=y;
// part of game .cpp
// the surprise is the first box the player is the second box 
//logique part
// i put the surprise class into vector 
for (int i=0;i<surprises.size();i++)
 {
SDL_Rect tmprect ={surprises[i]->getRect()->x-baseclass::coord.x,surprises[i]->getRect()->y,30,30};
if(collision(&tmprect,player1->getRect()))
 {
   for (int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
      surprises[i]->setyvel(-1);
      std::cout<<"increase the y coordinates  "<<surprises[i]->getyvel()->y<<std::endl;
    }
    for (int k=0;k<3;k++)
    {
     surprises[i]->setyvel(+1);
     std::cout<<"decrease the y coordinates "<<surprises[i]->getRect()->y<<std::endl;
    }
   }
}
//render part 
SDL_Flip(screen);
```

Comment: And the question is? Honestly i have no idea what are you describing in the two paragraphs.

Comment: Why do you print y *velocity* in the first loop (`for (int j=0;j<3;j++){...}`) and y *coordinate* in the second (`for (int k=0;k<3;k++){...}`)?

Comment: the question is the rectangle of the "monies[i]->getRect()->y" it move up but is not move down